# Getting Multiple drilldown highcharts on same page to work

Tags: .net, highcharts

I have 2 drill down charts on the same page inside 2 different div containers with different ids.

The parent level renders correctly but when i try to drill down the 2nd chart, the drill down operation takes place on the first chart. Can anyone decouple these 2 charts and tell me what am i doing wrong here. Thank you.

here is the jfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ePg89/

Here are the 2 divs:

```
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="container1" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use `setChart()` function for both chart and not recognise which chart should be changed. I advice to add parameter to function like chartID and then you can have control which item is updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ePg89/1/