# Using tidyverse, how can you generate new columns dynamically?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dynamic, tidyverse

Say I have a dataframe of tens of columns, and my custom function needs each one of these columns plus a number in a vector to give me the desired output. After being done with all that, I need to generate new column names based on the original column names in the dataframe. How to accomplish this using the `tidyverse`, instead of `for` loops or other solutions in `base R`.

**MWE**

```
structure(list(col1 = c(36.0520583373645, 37.9423749063706, 33.6806634587719, 
34.031649012457, 29.5448679963449, NA, 34.7576769718877, 30.484217745574, 
32.9849083643022, 27.4081694831058, 35.8624919654559, 35.0284347997991, 
NA, 32.112605893241, 27.819354948082, 35.6499532124921, 35.0265642403216, 
32.4006569441297, 30.3698557864842, 31.8229364456928, 34.3715903109276
), col2 = c(32.9691195198199, 35.6643664156284, 33.8748732989736, 
34.5436311813644, 33.2228201914256, 38.7621696867191, 34.8399804318992, 
32.9063078995457, 35.7391166214367, 32.7217251282669, 36.3039268989853, 
35.9607654868559, 33.1385915196435, 34.7987649028199, 33.7100463668523, 
34.7773403671057, 35.8592997980752, 33.8537127786535, 31.9106243803505, 
39.3099469314882, 35.1849826815196), col3 = c(33.272278716963, 
NA, 31.8594920410129, 33.1695042551974, 29.3800694974438, 35.1504378875245, 
34.0771487001433, 29.0162879030415, 30.6960024888799, 29.5542117965184, 
34.3726321365982, 36.0602274148362, 33.1207772548047, 31.5506876209822, 
28.8649303491974, 33.4598790144265, 30.5573454464747, 31.6026723913051, 
30.4716061556625, 33.009463000301, 30.846230953425)), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

save above in a file, and then use `example <- dget(file.choose())` to read the above dataframe.

**Code**

```
y <- c (2, 1, 1.5)

customfun <- function(x, y){
  n  <- log (x) * y
  print (n)
}

df <- example %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col1.log = customfun (col1, y = y[1])) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col2.log = customfun (col2, y = y[2])) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(col3.log = customfun (col3, y = y[3]))
```

**Question**

Imagine I have tens of these columns not only 3 as in the MWE, how to generate the new ones dynamically using the tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2` and `bind_cols` to add new columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

bind_cols(example, map2_df(example, y, customfun) %>%
                           rename_all(~paste0(., ".log"))) 

#       col1     col2     col3 col1.log col2.log col3.log
#1  36.05206 32.96912 33.27228 7.169928 3.495571 5.257087
#2  37.94237 35.66437       NA 7.272137 3.574152       NA
#3  33.68066 33.87487 31.85949 7.033848 3.522674 5.192003
#4  34.03165 34.54363 33.16950 7.054582 3.542223 5.252446
#...
```

Comment: nice verse written in the purr forest, I wonder how `map2_df` is any different from the other neighbor `map2_dfc` which seems to give similar output?

Comment: @doctorate yes, in this case you could use any of `map2_df`/`map2_dfc`/`map2_dfr` and it will give the same output. It differs in output when you operate it on list.

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` is not great for these `sweep()`-like operations, however, one option could be:

```
example %>%
 do(., sweep(., 2, FUN = customfun, y)) %>%
 rename_all(~ paste(., "log", sep = "."))

   col1.log col2.log col3.log
1  7.169928 3.495571 5.257087
2  7.272137 3.574152       NA
3  7.033848 3.522674 5.192003
4  7.054582 3.542223 5.252446
5  6.771820 3.503237 5.070475
6        NA 3.657445 5.339456
7  7.096801 3.550766 5.292941
8  6.834418 3.493664 5.051786
9  6.992100 3.576246 5.136199
10 6.621682 3.488039 5.079339
```

Comment: is it possible to preserve the original columns?

Comment: I would say that it is easier to just do a column bind as `example %>%
 do(., sweep(., 2, FUN = customfun, y)) %>%
 rename_all(~ paste(., "log", sep = ".")) %>%
 bind_cols(example)`.

Comment: fine, and my be someone would come up with another answers!

Comment: @tmfmnk could you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431981/how-to-create-two-independent-drill-down-plot-using-highcharter